# setState updating all state values rather than individually?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

Starting learning React and in my project I'm trying to generate a random number for each individual player when they click a button. I am reusing the `NumberGenerator` component for both players but unfortunately at the moment each button click sets the state for both players at the same time and does not allow for individual updating of states. Can anyone help me on this?

Appreciate your time,

```
    class App extends React.Component {
           state = {
            userScores : [
              {score: 0}
              {score: 0}
            ],
              buttonToggle: "enabled"
          }

 generateRandomNumber = (player) => {
    let randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
    if (player === 1) {
    this.setState({
      userScores : [
        {score: randomNumber}
      ],
        buttonToggle: '' 
    })
  } else {
    this.setState({
      userScores : [
        {score: randomNumber}
      ],
        buttonToggle: '' 
    })
  }
}

        render() {
          return (
            <div className="App">
              <h1> <u> Death Roll</u> </h1>
              <h4> Player 1 </h4>
              <NumberGenerator id = "p1" userscores = {this.state.userScores[0].score} generate = {() => this.generateRandomNumber(1)} buttontoggle = {this.state.buttonToggle}  />
              <h4> Player 2 </h4>
              <NumberGenerator userscores = {this.state.userScores[1].score} generate = {() => this.generateRandomNumber(2)} buttontoggle = {this.state.buttonToggle}  /> 
              <ScoreCard number = {this.state.userScores[1].score} />
            </div>
          );
          }
        }
```

Comment: Replace `this.generateRandomNumber` with `() => this.generateRandomNumber(0)` and use the passed index to only generate a new number for that player. (also bakar_dev's comment makes no sense, the main problem is that you're actively, deliberately doing the very thing you want to prevent: set both player's scores to the new random number)

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG - I have tried what you suggested and for some reason I get an error when trying to only include one score state in my if statement - only seems to work if I have both states included which means they still update at the same time

Comment: You need to research how to update a state array, how to replace one element while keeping the rest.